# Method as parameter for own annotation?

Tags: dart

I have this annotation:

```
class Handler {
  final Function onListen;
  final Function onPause;
  final Function onResume;
  final Function onCancel;

  const Handler({this.onListen, this.onPause, this.onResume, this.onCancel});
}
```

and use it like this:

```
abstract class Test implements ViewModel<TestController> {

  static onListen() {
    print('onListen');
  }

  @Handler(onListen: onListen)
  Stream<String> get messages;

  factory Test() = _$Test;
  Test._();
}
```

This works so far but is there a way to use a non `static` method as parameter for my annotation?

When I remove the `static` I get this error: Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, instance methods can't be const and annotations have to be const,
Therefore you can only have static methods or top-level functions as parameters for annotations.